# Серверная часть на python

Tags: python, сервер, django

Подскажите, опытные программисты, как правильно сделать следующую вещь: я написал парсеры, используя scrapy, он на языке python. Как с точки зрения правильного кода сделать так, чтобы один раз в 24 часа на сервере (удаленном облаке, на котором крутиться Django и слушает запросы клиентов) собиралась информация этими краулерами, заносилась в базу данных и затем обрабатывалась. Как сделать расписание выполнения задач, так чтобы не городить огород и не строчить кучу кода, а использовать готовые решения? Жду помощи и совета.

Comment: @partizander, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То есть надо, чтобы python скрипт запускался раз в 24 часа?

[cron](http://masterhost.ru/support/doc/cron/)

[cron](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/cron.php)

[python crontab api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)